# Delete element using key in hash with self

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm learning hash in Ruby.
I'm trying to iterate a hash without assigning it to any variable and delete its elements. `{a: 1, b: 2, c: "Hello"}.each{|k,v| self.delete(k)}`. I get this error

```
2.3.0 :001 > {a: 1, b: 2, c: "Hello"}.each {|k,v| self.delete(k)}
NoMethodError: undefined method `delete' for main:Object
    from (irb):1:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):1:in `each'
    from (irb):1
    from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

I also tried to replace `self` with `this` but it didn't work neither. Is there anyway I can use methods of hash (like `delete`) without assigning the hash to a variable (like `hash_var.each {|k,v| hash_var.delete(k)}`)? I'm using c9 IDE.

Comment: I want to play with hash. In an example, `number = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}; number.each {|k, v| number.delete(k) if v <3}`. I think maybe I can do the same thing, by directly work with {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3} instead of assigning the hash to a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ruby, `self` variable contains a link to the object that contains your block. In your sample this is `main` object. So, you right, you must explicitly scpecify variable `hash_var` in your block.

Also, it's seems you want to delete all keys from your hash. So use `delete_if` instead of `each` to delete selected items of the hash

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: "Hello"}.delete_if{|k,v| your_condition}
```

More:
http://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/delete_if

Or, if you want delete all keys from hash and get array from it you must use `values` method:

```
 {a: 1, b: 2, c: "Hello"}.values
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm just curious and trying to work directly with a hash like doing so with a hash variable.

Answer (score 2):

Answering to your question “to iterate a hash without assigning it to any variable”: one might use [`Object#tap`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Object.html#method-i-tap):

```
{a: 1, b: 2, c: "Hello"}.tap { |h| h.each { |k,v| h.delete(k) } }
#⇒ {}
```